# Azure Function - C# save a temp file B64 decoded

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I need to build an Azure Function in C# able to gather a string and save it as local temporary Base64 file.
This is the function code:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(Stream req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var temp = @"C:\home\site\wwwroot\CallFFMpeg\test.webm";
    var tempOut = @"C:\home\site\wwwroot\CallFFMpeg\test.wav";
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
    req.CopyTo(ms);
    //File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\home\site\wwwroot\CallFFMpeg\test.webm", ms.ToArray());
    byte[] textToByte = Convert.FromBase64String(ms);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\home\site\wwwroot\CallFFMpeg\test.webm", textToByte);
    }
}
```

I the Body Request I'm simply posting the base64 has file (it's an Webm audio).

I have this error:

```
2021-01-20T15:41:00.283 [Error] run.csx(11,20): error CS1061: 'Stream' does not contain a definition for 'FromBase64String' and no accessible extension method 'FromBase64String' accepting a first argument of type 'Stream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-01-20T15:41:00.403 [Error] run.csx(18,50): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to 'string'
2021-01-20T15:41:00.458 [Information] Compilation failed.
```

I'm really strugling on how to treat the Stream request and trasform in Base64.
Many thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: The error is quite specific. What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: `byte[] textToByte = ms.ToArray()`?

Comment: @IanKemp I don't understand how do create base64 file from the HTTP request stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you want to upload a binary file such as .wav or .webm to your Azure function by HTTP request and save it to the Azure function side.

If you are coding on Portal directly, Just try the code below:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    
    var tempFilePath = "d:/home/" + req.Query["filename"]; ;

    using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        new StreamReader(req.Body).BaseStream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
    }
    return new OkObjectResult("file has been sent");

}
```

Result:
[image]

You can check if the file has been uploaded to `/home` folder by `Console` on Portal:

[image]

Comment: Here error after trying it:  error CS7021: Cannot declare namespace in script code
 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions' 
 [Error] run.csx(15,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpTriggerAttribute' could not be found
  The type or namespace name 'HttpTrigger' could not be found
 run.csx(15,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Route' could not be found

Comment: @user3925023 Seems you are using Azure portal to code your function directly, I have updated my answer.